# Inconsistent ordering of parent:child group names in inventory file

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am now experiencing a typical problem in ansible V 2.1.0. In the case below,

```
[DEV:children]
DEV8
[DEV8]
thehost ansible_ssh_host=10.2.131.26 ansible_ssh_user=someuser1
```

Now, the when I run

```
{{hostvars[inventory_hostname].group_names, it outputs

TASK [debug]          ************************************************************
ok: [thehost] => {
"msg": [
"DEV",
"DEV8"
]
}
```

Now, for other group of machines

```
[PRODCTE:children]
CTE3
[CTE3]
thehost1 ansible_ssh_host=10.2.131.30 ansible_ssh_user=someuser2

output:
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [thehost] => {
"msg": [
"CTE3",
"PRODCTE"
]
}
```

PROBLEM:

```
[PROD]
PRODA
[PRODA]
PROD1
[PROD1]
thehost2 ansible_ssh_host=10.2.3.33 ansible_ssh_user=someuser3

output:
TASK [debug]    *******************************************************************
ok: [thehost] => {
"msg": [
"PROD",
"PROD1"
"PRODA"
]
}
```

Now, If ansible code is to execute alphabetically, then consistency cannot be achieved. The output always has to be consistent. I mean, if group_names[0] or group_names[1] shows me different values for different groups based alphabetically, the playbooks cannot be standardized.

Anyways, even if go with this behavior, I am trying to understand on what factors does ansible outputs these values?

If alphabetically, then how was PROD1 chosen over PRODA? Does ansible considers numerics to be priority than alphabets here?

Answer (score 0):

Why should it be parent->children?

I guess it is supposed to be alphabetically sorted. From [code](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/inventory/host.py#L135):

```
results['group_names'] = sorted([ g.name for g in self.get_groups() if g.name != 'all'])
```